# Sage error while calculating square root in finite field

Tags: typeerror, sage

> Error message:
> TypeError: not in prime subfield
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> TypeError: unable to convert z^3 + z + 1 to a rational
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError: z^3 + z + 1 is not in the image of (map internal to coercion system -- copy before use)
> Ring morphism:
> From: Finite Field of size 2
> To:   Finite Field in z of size 2^4

I just want to calculate the square root of a polynomial in a finite field in sage. I know it exists and can be calculated by taking the square root of each coefficient multiplied by the variable^(exponent/2) because only even exponents occur - how can I implement that?

my code works with binary goppa polynomials g but not with general goppa polynomials - the problem is the conversion of something

those were the used variables

K ist defined as follows (so F_2^m):

```py
f = irreducibles_z[0]
    #Now we can initialise the field
    K.<z> =  GF(2^m, modulus = f)
return K
```

> sigma [z^2, z^3 + z^2 + 1, z^3 + z^2 + z, z, 0, z^3 + z, z^3 + z + 1, 1, z + 1, z^3, z^3 + 1, z^3 + z^2 + z + 1, z^3 + z^2, z^2 + z + 1, z^2 + z, z^2 + 1]

> g (z^2 + z + 1)*x^3 + (z^3 + z^2 + z + 1)*x^2 + (z^3 + z^2 + 1)*x + z^3 + z + 1

> K Finite Field in z of size 2^4

> t 3

> m 4

> n 16

> k 4

> G Univariate Quotient Polynomial Ring in x over Finite Field in z of size 2^4 with modulus x^3 + z^2*x^2 + z^3*x + z^3 + z^2 + z + 1

> Sw (z^2 + z)*x^2 + z^2*x + z^2 + z + 1

this function was called

```py
v = calculate_v(g, K, t, Sw, verbose)
```

it does the following

```py
def calculate_v(g, K, t, Sw, verbose):
    #This helper field with indeterminate b is used 
    # to check for all x's if they are a square, 
    #as this functionality is not available for 
    # F_{2^m}[x]/g(x,z), but is available for F_{2^t}
    G.<x> = K.extension(g)
    _.<b> = GF(2)[]
    --> ERROR: SqrtField.<b> = GF(2^t, modulus = g(b))

    #This helper function checks for all pairs of 
    # C_i*x^i if c_i is a square and x^i is a square, 
    #because only then c_i*x^i is a square
    def is_square_f2mx(el):
        coefs = list(el)
        result = True
        for index,coef in enumerate(coefs):
            if coef != 0:
                result = result and (b^index).is_square() and coef.is_square()
        return result

    #This helper function converts an element from helper
    # field SqrtField back to F_{2^m}[x]/g(x)
    def b_to_x(element):
        xcoefs = element.polynomial().coefficients(sparse = False)
        xvalue = 0
        for exponent,xcoef in enumerate(xcoefs):
            if xcoef != 0:
                xvalue += x^exponent
        return xvalue

    #Using the observation from the previous cell, 
    # this function calculates the square root 
    # of an element in F_{2^m}[x]
    #by taking the square root of each coefficient c_i 
    # and each x^i separately 
    # and then multiplying them afterwards
    def sqrt_f2mx(element, Sw):
        # assert is_square_f2mx(element), "not a square"
        result = 0
        for index,coef in enumerate(list(element)):
            if coef != 0:
                #bsquare_for_x = sqrt(b^index)
                #xsquare = b_to_x(bsquare_for_x)
                coefsqrt = sqrt(coef)
                result += coefsqrt*x ^(index/2) #xsquare
        return result
    
    v = sqrt_f2mx(x + Sw^-1, Sw)
    if verbose:
        latexprint(r"\text{This is our polynomial }V(x,z)")
        latexprint(latex(v))
    return v
```

The problem is THIS LINE `SqrtField.<b> = GF(2^t, modulus = g(b))` DOES NOT WORK.
WITH BINARY polynomials g it works (all coefficients in GF(2) but with coefficients in GF(2^m) it does not work

any suggestions

and thanks for your help!